# Gigantic arrow heads when plotting network with igraph

Tags: plot, social-networking, igraph

**EDIT**
I was trying to figure out what is wrong with my code and I started to plot simple graphs to see how the arrow will look on smaller graphs. I tired the following command:

```
 g2 <- graph( edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3, 1), n=10 ) 
 plot(g2)
```

And here is my graph: [image]. Thus, I think the problem is not with my code but either with igraph or R. I re-installed both, igraph and R but it did not solve the problem. Is it possible that there is a conflict of packages that leads to this? Here is a lit of packages that I have installed:

```
 [1] "base"         "boot"         "class"        "cluster"     
 [5] "codetools"    "colorspace"   "compiler"     "datasets"    
 [9] "dichromat"    "digest"       "doParallel"   "foreach"     
[13] "foreign"      "graphics"     "grDevices"    "grid"        
[17] "gridBase"     "gtable"       "igraph"       "irlba"       
[21] "iterators"    "KernSmooth"   "labeling"     "lattice"     
[25] "lazyeval"     "magrittr"     "MASS"         "Matrix"      
[29] "methods"      "mgcv"         "munsell"      "nlme"        
[33] "NMF"          "nnet"         "parallel"     "pkgmaker"    
[37] "plyr"         "RColorBrewer" "Rcpp"         "registry"    
[41] "reshape2"     "rngtools"     "rpart"        "scales"      
[45] "spatial"      "splines"      "stats"        "stats4"      
[49] "stringi"      "stringr"      "survival"     "tcltk"       
[53] "tibble"       "tools"        "utils"        "xtable"
```

---

I am trying to generate a plot of a network and for some reason I my arrowheads look like small rectangles instead of the usual triangle arrowheads.

Here is the code I am using for my plots:

```
toy.edges <- na.omit(read.csv("Data/Edge_list-toy.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = "numeric", na.strings = c("NA", "", "#N/A")))
toy.nodes <- na.omit(read.csv("Data/NodesDataF-toy.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = c("NA", "", "#N/A")))
toy.graph <- graph_from_data_frame(toy.edges, directed = TRUE, vertices = toy.nodes)

V(toy.graph)$color <- "magenta" 
V(toy.graph)$shape <- "sphere"
V(toy.graph)$size <- 3*15^(ifelse(is.na(V(toy.graph)$node.size), 0.001, 
V(toy.graph)$node.size))
plot(toy.graph, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(toy.graph),
     vertex.label=NA, edge.width=E(toy.graph)$weight, 
     edge.arrow.size=0.005, edge.arrow.width=0.0000001)
```

And here is an example plot:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCx]

It looks even worse when I take slightly bigger values for `edge.arrow.size` 
 and `edge.arrow.width`.

What is wrong with my code? Can it have something to do with the version of R? I made a ton of plots before, using very similar command, and I never had problems.

Here are files with [nodes info](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gp1ec04g5brt19s/NodesDataF-toy.csv?dl=0) and [edge list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ricg41rplqdc5cj/Edge_list-toy.csv?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like the problem is with how R displays graphic on my computer. When, instead of plotting the figure directly in the console, I save it to a file, everything looks just fine. Here is a code I am using, in case someone else faces similar problem:

```
png("my-plot.png", width=1200, height=1200)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(mat_gr, layout = layout.auto(mat_gr), vertex.label=NA,   
     edge.width=E(mat_gr)$weight)
dev.off()
```

I realize it does not solve the problem with displaying gigantic arrowheads but at least it allows to generate as save usable plots.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter ***edge.arrow.size*** may help to reduce the arrow head size. There are more information available via this [link](https://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html) to the documentation of the plot function. Basically, we can use all listed parameters by adding either vertex/edge in front of the parameters.

```
plot(g2, edge.arrow.size = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `plot.igraph()` rather than simply `plot()` may be of help here.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Why would it be of help here?